# Undefined index after using mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php

I need help fixing my PHP error: `undefined index id_user`. I don't know why my code doesn't get `id_user` after using `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    include "connect.php";  
    $id_user_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id_user_add']);
    $name_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name_add']);
    $authority_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['authority_add']);
    $email_user_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email_user_add']);
}
else
{
    echo '<script> alert("You Have No Privilege"); </script>';
    echo '<script>window.location.href = "../index.php";</script>';
}
?>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: what's the full error you have, the undefined index is likely for an array key that is missing and has nothing to do with the function.

Comment: dont you mean `id_user_add` not `id_user` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your post array is missing the value for that index, no amount of `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is going to create it where it doesn't first exist.

`mysqli_real_escape_string()` operates on your array, it can't magically create array values that don't exist.

I suggest you print out the full `$_POST` array and check that all the data you need actually exists.  This can be done with

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

AS to how you fill that missing data in, without knowing how the post is done it's impossible to answer.

You could check it many ways, even fill it in when its missing. but is it required, that I have no idea.

```
if( isset($_POST['id_user_add']) )
    ///do something
```

Or

```
$id_user_add = isset($_POST['id_user_add']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id_user_add']) : false;
```